# Mongo Shell : Filter getCollectionNames() by name

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

In mongo shell, I am trying to filter the list of collections that is returned by `db.getCollectionNames()`

```
db.getCollectionNames()
[ 
  "abc_1",
  "abc_2",
  "abc_3",
  "def_1",
  "def_2"
]
```

**Expected output :**

I would like to keep only collections that start with "abc"

```
db.getCollectionNames().someFunction()
[ 
  "abc_1",
  "abc_2",
  "abc_3"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular javascript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(col){return col.match(/^abc/)})
```